# How to Change Autorefname of Subfigure

Tags: cross-referencing, labels, subcaption, autoref

I currently started to use the `subfigure` command instead of `minipage` to arrange several figures. I am using the `subcaption` package to do so. Now `subfigure` (other than `minipage`) references in the written text - when using `\autoref{ExampleLabel}` - as `Abbildung 1a`. While I do like the (a), (b), (c), (d) label format I would like the reference to be like `Abbildung 1 (a)` with both parenthesis and the blank in between.

**How do I approach this?**

[image: Label format of subfigure (a), (b), (c), (d)]

[image: \autoref referenc in text without a blank and parenthesis]

Comment: Probably the following quote from page 9 of the `subcaption` manual can help: "If you want parentheses around the sub-figure part of the reference, so they will look like ‘1(a)’, you may get them this way: `\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption}\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}`"

Answer (score 1):

As @Mico stated in the Comments:

The `subcaption` user manual stats on page 9:

"If you want parentheses around the sub-figure part of the reference, so they will look like ‘1(a)’, you may get them this way:"

```
\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}
```

If one wants to have "1 (a)" - so with a blank in between - instead on "1(a)", one has to add the blank such as: `\renewcommand\thesubfigure{ (\alph{subfigure})}`.

If one uses `\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\,(\alph{subfigure})}` it will be a half blank and `1 (a)` never gets separated.